# Graph properties characterized by finitely many 'simplest examples'

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Recently I heard someone talking about a general result saying that a graph property satisfying certain conditions always is characterizable via a (finite) set of 'smallest examples' (similar to the famous characterization of non-planar graphs as those that contain either the complete 5-graph or the 3-3 graph).

Does anyone recognize what I'm talking about?
Where can I find more details on this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's probably it. (How to accept a comment?)

Comment: You can't, but I added it as an answer.  Sorry I can't explicate more but I'm barely familiar with this subject.

Answer (score 3):

You must be looking for the [Robertson-Seymour theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem) which generalizes Kuratowski's planar graph theorem.